# Java removing subset of a nested map containing list, then reversing map

Tags: java, list, dictionary, hashmap

I currently have some data in the form of a nested map like the following:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Integer>>> data = // intializing the Map
    
// data = {group1={grades=[a,b,c], age=[x,y,z]}, group={....}} and so on
```

What I want to do is essentially remove grades and then reverse the map, so it would look something like:

```
{x={group1}, y={group1, group3}, z={group2}, someAge={some list of groupN}}
```

I appreciate that the data may not make sense without context, but the problem remains the same. As it stands, I have a 3-nested for loops, but there must be a better way, since that would be very inefficient with a large dataset:

```
Map <Integer, List<String>> someMap = new HashMap<>();

for (var entry : data.entrySet()) {
    for (var info : entry.getValue().entrySet()) {
        if (info.getKey().equals("age")) {
            List ages = info.getValue();
            for (var age : ages) {
                // if age not in someMap, add age as key // e.g add x so someMap={x={},y={}}
                someMap.get(age).add(entry.getKey()) //e.g {x={entry key},y={}}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some kind of pre-processing I can do to remove grades which would cut the 2nd for loop in half at least, and remove the need to check if the key is 'age' each iteration.

Comment: Why don't you use [Map.get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-) instead of iteration?

Comment: @Chaosfire Sorry, how would I use that in this scenario. Are you saying, inside the first for loop, I would do:  entry.get("age") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the second nested `for`-loop where you're iterating over the entry sets of the *inner Map* searching for the *key* `"age"`. Instead, you can retrieve a value that corresponds to this *key* from each *inner Map*.

That's how your logic can be implemented using Java 8 methods [`Map.computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) and [`Map.forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#forEach(java.util.function.BiConsumer)).

As a precaution against the case when the *key* `"age"` is not present in the inner Map you can use [`Map.getOrDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault(java.lang.Object,V))

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Integer>>> data = // {group1={grades=[a,b,c], age=[x,y,z]}, group={....}} and so on
        
Map<Integer, List<String>> groupsByAge = new HashMap<>();


data.forEach((group, nestedMap) -> {
    nestedMap.getOrDefault("age", List.of()).forEach(age -> 
        groupsByAge.computeIfAbsent(age, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(group)
    );
});
```

#### Note

It's also worth to note that your data is **not dynamic**, i.e. **every** nested Map is expected to have Keys: `"grades"`, `"age"`, etc. Then it should be an object having properties `grades` and `age`. Because custom domain object allows to structure the data, utilize appropriate data types and manipulate with data using custom behavior. As an example, simple getters `getAge()` / `getGrades()` would be less error-prone and more readable than calls `get("age")` / `get("grades")`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Map.get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get-java.lang.Object-), instead of iteration to find the value of a key.

```
for(var entry : data.entrySet()) {
  var ages = entry.getValue().get("age");
  if (ages == null) {
    //key does not exist
    //initialize or whatever you need
  } else {
    //key exists
    //operate on list
  }
}
```